# Help with Find() in the BindingSource

Tags: c#, datagridview, bindingsource

I use this to look for values in my DataGridView:

```
private void fndBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BindingSource src = new BindingSource();
            src.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;

            src.Position = src.Find("p_Name", textBox1.Text);
        }
```

But I've two issues. First when I look for item that doesn't exist in my dgv, position returns 0 which is by default the first row. I don't want that, and if I verified using If statement I'll lose position 0, thus losing the first row.

Second is I want the row header be focused on and item found be highlighted. How is that possible?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use dataGridView's binding source like this:

```
private void fndBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindingSource src = new BindingSource();
    src.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
    int findedRow = 0;
    if (textBox1.Text!="")
          findedRow = src.Find("p_Name", textBox1.Text); 
    if (findedRow!=-1)
           src.Position = findedRow ;
}
```

Comment: Then how can I display the first column in that position?

Comment: `dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0];`

Comment: If you don't set position to value >= 0 then its binding source default position is 0. Better way is: int pos=bindingsource.find("..", val) then use pos to check if search returned value if = -1 or >=0